# Get input field of a dialog in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dialog, title

For my plugin, I try to get the active Eclipse dialog with these lines:

```
String shellTitle = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell().getTitle();
System.out.println("Opened dialog: " + shellTitle);
```

If e.g. I open the search dialog, these lines print me

```
Opened dialog: Search
```

in my console. But I would also want to print the keyword in the search field, for example

```
Opened dialog: Search (with the search word 'ChatSession')
```

I have read the API reference and there, I just can found the `getTitle()` and some other methods for getting bounds and so on.

Is my idea realizable? And if not, is it realizable with these so-called extension points? I have never used them but heard of them.

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes in your question:

1. You are calling `getTitle()` method on Shell array object. It is wrong.
2. You are mixing dialog and Shell

Assuming you are talking about Shell. You can use the below code to get the controls on active Shell.

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class ShellControlsGetting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Open 3 Shells");
        final Shell[] shells = new Shell[3];
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    shells[i] = new Shell(shell);
                    shells[i].setText("Shell" + (i + 1));
                    shells[i].setLayout(new FillLayout());
                    shells[i].setSize(250, 50);
                    shells[i].setLocation(100, 200 + (i + 1) * 100);

                    Label label = new Label(shells[i], SWT.LEFT);
                    label.setText("Search Box" + (i + 1));

                    Text search = new Text(shells[i], SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
                    search.setText("search key" + (i + 1));
                    shells[i].open();
                }

                Shell currentActiveShell = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
                String shellTitle = currentActiveShell.getText();

                Control[] children = currentActiveShell.getChildren();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    Control child = children[i];
                    if (child instanceof Text) {
                        System.out.println("Opened dialog: " + shellTitle + "(with the search word '" + ((Text)child).getText()
                                + "')");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

If this not answers you question then edit your post add some code and clarify what exactly you are expecting.

Comment: I am talking about dialogs. With my code above I find out which dialog the user opened. But if the user for example opens the search dialog, I also want to get the entered word in the search dialog. Or if the user opens the "new java class" dialog, I want to get which name he/she entered in the new class dialog. And I am not sure if this is possible with the Shell-Object? And do I have to write extensions to all dialogs, where I want special information. Thus more than just the title.